# How to display values at right side or down in Treemap in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

Hi I am new for this High-charts, I am using Tree-map of High-charts,If I saw output in small system values are coming out of box so how to make it responsive or how to display all values at right side like how pie chart all values displaying right side http://jsfiddle.net/7fb3x9ys/. Here is code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: "treemap",
        layoutAlgorithm: 'stripes',
        alternateStartingDirection: true,
        levels: [{
            level: 1,
            layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        }],
        data: [{
            id: 'A',
            name: 'Apples',
            color: "#EC2500"
        }, {
            id: 'B',
            name: 'Bananas',
            color: "#ECE100"
        }, {
            id: 'O',
            name: 'Oranges',
            color: '#EC9800'
        }, {
            name: 'Susanne',
            parent: 'Kiwi',
            value: 2,
            color: '#9EDE00'
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit consumption'
    }
});
```

Comment: Please create a `jsfiddle` with the similar problem.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the problem. To align data labels, simply use `align` parameter. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jc9uhqpx/.

Comment: my requirement is to display treemap values like how pie charts values displaying right side .http://jsfiddle.net/7fb3x9ys/